# PySpark - converting single element arrays/lists to string

Tags: python, list, dataframe, pyspark

Let's say I have a df like this:

```
   id  type  length  key1             key2     key3
0  1   A     144     [value1,value2]  value3
1  1   B     20      value4           [value5]
2  4   A     54                                [value6]
```

Is there a way in PySpark I can get value5 and value6 out of the list since they are the only elements? I want to apply this to all cells. Output would be:

```
   id  type  length  key1             key2     key3
0  1   A     144     [value1,value2]  value3
1  1   B     20      value4           value5
2  4   A     54                                value6
```

Comment: Can you please give a try to the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
    Df= df.withColumn('key3', F.when(F.size('key3) ==1),F.col('key3').getItem(1)  ).when(F.size('column_2) ==1),F.col('column_2').getItem(1))
 .otherwise ('key3')
```

You can keep adding the condition like this

```
.when(F.size('col_2) ==1),F.col('col_2').getItem(1))
```

First you need to find the size of the array and if found 1 then get the first element. I responded through mobile, please give it a try, I believe it should work

Comment: This is only for one column though. Also, what is `F`?

Comment: I would like to apply it to allcells in the dataframe.

Comment: To get `F`, run `import pyspark.sql.functions as F`

Comment: Can you please approve the answer if it serves the purpose.. Thanks in advance

Comment: @dsk I did not, sorry. Also, is there a way to easily apply this to whole df? There are many columns.